# What is the meaning of below code (DI injection of proxy)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, di, proxy

Can someone explain me what does this code does, when we need this.

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data"> 
    <arguments> 
        <argument name="customerSession" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Proxy</argument> 
    </arguments> 
</type>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check **Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data::__constructor()** method, you will find there the following argument:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    ...
) {
    ...
}
```

The code that you provided is replacing **Magento\Customer\Model\Session** class with its proxy. In simple words, Proxies are used for reducing the number of loaded objects. Here is how it works in this particular case:

*Without Proxy:*

If you create an object for **Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data** class, then it will also create an object for **Magento\Customer\Model\Session** and as result it will also create objects for all the dependencies of the **Magento\Customer\Model\Session** class and so on

*With Proxy*

If you create an object for **Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data** class, the object for **Magento\Customer\Model\Session** class will not be created until you call one of its methods (like $customerSession->getCustomerId() or any other).

You can find more information in [Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/proxies.html)

Comment: lets say in di.xml file instead of PROXY , if i pass \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession then do i need to pass explicitly \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession in my class construction. As per above comment it will create an object for session. Then in my class if i did not specify \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession what would happen

Answer (score 0):

It is a dependency injection, on the Magento \ Wishlist \ Helper \ Data class we inject the Magento \ Customer \ Model \ Session \ Proxy class this class or this object will replace the customerSession variable in all the instance.

From what I see it is the use of the design pattern which allows to replace a class by its proxy. you can have more information on the devDocs

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/proxies.html

Comment: what would happen if i extend this class Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data

Comment: nothing is invisible to you